# Facebook custom share button not showing description

Tags: javascript, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I am using following JS code for sharing on facebook.

```
function openFbPopUp() {
    var fburl = 'http://54.251.121.6/cnc/cupcakes-n-chai-side-table';
    var fbimgurl = 'http://imageURL';
    var fbtitle = 'Your title';
    var fbsummary = "This is the description blah blah blah";
    var sharerURL = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=" + encodeURI(fburl) + "&p[images][0]=" + encodeURI(fbimgurl) + "&p[title]=" + encodeURI(fbtitle) + "&p[summary]=" + encodeURI(fbsummary);
    window.open(
      sharerURL,
      'facebook-share-dialog', 
      'width=626,height=436'); 
    return  false;
}
```

In the pop-up window, the Description text seems fine. But when seen in facebook, the description does not show up

While sharing, **Description(summary text)** can be seen.
[image: Description Can be seen]

But **Description(summary text)** not showing in facebook.

[image: Description not showing up]

Answer (score 0):

On whatever page you're sharing, try putting the following:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{Your_App_ID}"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://54.251.121.6/cnc/cupcakes-n-chai-side-table"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Your title"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://imageURL"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="This is the description blah blah blah">
```

However, if you're already using JS, how about using the Facebook JS SDK?

Just put the following code right after your  tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '{your-app-id}',
      status     : true,
      xfbml      : true
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Then, to invoke the share dialog, just call the following:

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'Your title',
        link: 'http://54.251.121.6/cnc/cupcakes-n-chai-side-table',
        picture: 'http://imageURL',
        caption: '',
        description: 'This is the description blah blah blah',
        ref: '{your_reference_call_here}'
});
```

My personal experience suggests using the JS SDK to share things is much safer (ensures no bugs) than using the URL Redirection method.

Comment: Thanks @Aashish Tripathee . I can not use meta description tag because there are pages where we need 3-4 different meta description tags on different blocks of a page.

Comment: Then try using the JS SDK. That definitely works and is really good when it comes to having multiple contents to share like in your case.:)